# Sitemap.xml not working in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sitemap

I am able to build the sitemap.xml in my dev environment, but on pushing it to production environment I keep getting this error.

```
XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </link>.
Location: https://www.sample.com/sitemap.xml
Line Number 68, Column 4: </head>       
---^
```

In controller I have it like this:

```
  def sitemap
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml'

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml
    end
  end
```

The view is like this (sitemap.xml.builder):

```
xml.instruct! :xml, :version=>'1.0'
xml.tag! 'urlset', "xmlns" => "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" do

  if Rails.env.production? 
    base_url = "https://#{request.host_with_port}"
  else
    base_url = "http://#{request.host_with_port}"
  end

  xml.tag! "link", rel: 'alternate', hreflang: "en", href: base_url

  xml.url do
   xml.loc base_url
   xml.lastmod "2015-01-01"
   xml.changefreq "yearly"
   xml.priority 1.0
  end  

 xml.url do
  xml.loc "#{base_url}/intro"
  xml.lastmod "2016-04-03"
  xml.changefreq "monthly"
  xml.priority 1.0
 end 

end
```

Generated XML:

```
<urlset>
  <url>
   <loc>http://localhost:3001</loc>
   <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
   <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://localhost:3001/blogs</loc>
    <lastmod>2016-04-03</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
   </url>
   <url>
    <loc>http://localhost:3001/sample_links/blog1</loc>  
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

### Update:

I have fixed the issue, there was a code error where some field was empty and was causing an error.

Comment: Just add a link to gist with your built XML document. It should be a simple problem.

Comment: Can you please explain it?

Comment: as I can see, your builder makes wrong XML, so we just need to check XML output.

Comment: In my local environment it displays the xml without any issue.

Comment: Is posted XML the one generated on production environment? If not, please post XML from production.

Comment: In production as I am getting an error, I cannot get the sitemap.xml. But the xml is getting generated as it should in my local env.

Comment: As I can see, error `XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag.` is an error in your browser, isn't it? XML still should be available via "view source".

Comment: I see html code if I try to view the source.

Comment: Yup, and that's exactly what you need to post here for debugging.

Comment: @Jehy, fixed the error it was an code issue which was not triggering a mail alert, finally fixed it. Thanks for the help.